# Page format messed up on double click (Google Chrome)

Tags: google-chrome

Recently, I've had this strange happening on my Chrome browser. On many sites, sometimes, when I double click (I think that's what made it happen), the entire layout of the webpage is disoriented. Here's an example:

**Original:**
[image]

**Messed up:**
[image]

Notice the horizontal scroll-bar and the text alignment; is there anything I did wrong? Does anyone have a similar experience? It's getting quite annoying.

**Note:** After the page gets disoriented, when I reload it, it gets re-oriented.